# how to pass file input value to JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i want to pass the file input value to `jQuery` function, it can be a multiple file. so how i can do that ? 
below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<input id="images" name="images[]" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple/>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('#images').change(function(){
   var input = document.getElementById("images");

     uploadImages(input); 
/* what should I pass to this function . this function have $.ajax method, which will upload images folder */ 


   });
```

Comment: You can simply pass `this.value` in function

Comment: but it can have multiple images , then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have, yet, methods to access data from an `<input type="file">`, however you can use the [File interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) for modern browsers (FF7+, Chrome13+, IE10+).

If you just want the data to be submited through AJAX, you can use the [FormData interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), which is much easier, in my opinion. MDN has even examples on [how to use it with jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the file inputs by name in an array like,
You can use `.map()` function for this

```
var fileNames = $('input[name="images[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

and treat as array in you function.
Please see the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QRNyJ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
<div id="files-selected"></div>


$(':file').change(function () {
$('#files-selected').text(this.files.length + " file selected");
alert(this.value); });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this  <kbd>[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hq6G6/)</kbd>

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#FileInput').change(function(){
    var numOfFile = document.getElementById('FileInput');

    for (var i = 0; i < FileInput.files.length; ++i) {
       var name = FileInput.files.item(i).name;
       alert("here is a file name: " + name);
    }
  });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<input type='file' id='FileInput' multiple='multiple'></input>
```

Hope this help you!